# How to create custom Forms Validator using a Service?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms, angular-services, injectable

I created an Injectable Service for a custom Form Validator:

```typescript
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
    import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms'
    import { Observable, of, timer } from 'rxjs'
    import { map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators'
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class IsValidNicknameService {
    
      validate = (time: number = 500) => {
        return (input: FormControl) => {
          return timer(time).pipe(
            switchMap(() => this.isValidNickname(input.value)),
            map(isValid => {
              return isValid ? null : { shouldNotStartWithA: true }
            })
          )
        }
      }
    
      private isValidNickname(value: string): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.checkIfFirstLetterIsA(value)
      }
    
      private checkIfFirstLetterIsA(value: string): Observable<boolean> {
        const firstCharacter = value.toLowerCase().charAt(0)
        if (firstCharacter === 'a' || firstCharacter === 'à' || firstCharacter === 'ä' || firstCharacter === 'á' || firstCharacter === 'ã') {
          return of(false)
        } else {
          return of(true)
        }
      }
    
    }
```

Then I call it in my controller like that:

```typescript
    import { IsValidNicknameService } from './src/Core/Services/isvalidnickname.service'
    createNicknamesGroup(): any {
      return new FormGroup({
        buildingRoom: new FormControl(this.mockBuildingRooms[0], Validators.required),
        nickname: new FormControl('', Validators.required, this.isValidNicknameService.validate())
      })
    }
```

It works, but I have the feeling it's not a good approach. Is there a better and more concise way to achieve that?

Comment: That is almost the recommended way. I would just quit using a class and making it injectable. Instead simply use a function. You didn't inject the service anyway. You can read more about it here: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators

Answer (score 1):

There is no correct or incorrect approaches here - do whatever feels comfortable for you.

From your code - you don't have any service dependencies so your service can be easily converted to a bunch of functions. An advantage of using plain functions is that they can be easily covered with unit tests.

Generally speaking, you'd want to use an `@Injectable()` class in case of some dependencies required to be injected in your constructor via Angular's DI. But this can also be avoided by passing the necessary dependencies to your validator [higher order function](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/higher-order-functions-composing-software-5365cf2cbe99):

```
# my-custom.validator.ts

export const setupRequiredValidator(minLength: number, someCheckerService: CheckerService): ValidatorFn => {
 return (control: AbstractControl) => {
   return control.value.length >= minLength && someCheckerService.check(control);
 }
}
```

```
# my.component.ts

constructor(private someCheckerService: CheckerService) {
}

createNicknamesGroup(): FormGroup {
  return new FormGroup({
      buildingRoom: new FormControl(this.mockBuildingRooms[0], Validators.required),
      nickname: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, setupRequiredValidator(5, this.someCheckerService)])
    }) // an example of synchronous validator
  }
```

Also you can create `@Injectable()` validator and don't call it a `Service` - no one will swear on you.

```
# my-custom.validator.ts

@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyCustomValidator {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  validateName = (control: AbstractControl) => {
    // try to do only one validation per method if there are no dependencies between the validators. 
    // It's easier to combine and tests them afterwards
    return control.value ? null : {error: 'text'};
  }

  validateEmail = (control: AbstractControl) => {
    return control.value ? Validators.email(control) : null;
  }

  validateSurnameIfTheNameExists = (control: AbstractControl) => {
    return control.parent.get('name').valid ? null : this.router.navigate(['/error']);
  }
}
```